# Unable to show data in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I am adding a feature in chatter package and now am unable to show data on my view
this is the code of controller ChatterreplyController.php

```
    <?php

namespace DevDojo\Chatter\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DevDojo\Chatter\Models\Chatterreply;
use Auth;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use DevDojo\Chatter\Events\ChatterAfterNewDiscussion;
use DevDojo\Chatter\Events\ChatterBeforeNewDiscussion;
use DevDojo\Chatter\Models\Models;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as Controller;
use Event;
use Validator;

class ChatterreplyController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $chatterreply =  new Chatterreply;
        $chatterreply->reply = $request->body;
        $chatterreply->chatter_post_id = $request->chatter_post_id;
        $chatterreply->chatter_discussion_id = $request->chatter_discussion_id;
        $chatterreply->save();
        return back()->with('chatter_alert','Add Comment Successfully');
    }


    public function show(Chatterreply $chatterreply ,$id)
    {
        $chatterreplies = Chatterreply::where('chatter_post_id',$id)->get();
        return view('chatter::discussion', compact('chatterreplies'));
        echo "<pre>"; print_r('$chatterreplies'); die;
    }
}
```

this is the view page discussion.blade.php

```
@foreach($chatterreplies as $chatterreply)
    {{$chatterreply->reply}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Can you add the fullpath for the blade file discussion?

Comment: may be you don't have any data ? and you should dump your var before said `return`. And also you can use `dd()` method for dump your vars in laravel

Comment: no that's not possible as the syntax of 5.6 is what I have written @Rafael

Comment: Sorry, let me rephrase myself: Can you add the fullpath for the blade file *discussion* in the **question**?

Comment: vendor\devdojo\chatter\src\Views\discussion.blade.php is the path of the view @Rafael

Comment: I think this might not be a problem specific with Laravel, @Vardana, but with the component you are using. You could test that by trying to read this variable in the local blade files stored in the resources/views folder.

Comment: ok thanks I will try that

Comment: Do try and let us know what happened, please.

Comment: same error undefined variable  on the resources/view at welcome.blade.php @Rafael

Comment: Ok. Try the following: **return view('welcome', ['test' => 'ping']);** and the output of $test variable in the blade, please.

Comment: I did it but what is variable here @Rafael

Comment: The variable in the blade will be **$test**. I believe this is the most common ground for declaring variables for the view files.

Comment: its showing undefined variable error

Comment: Ok, from what it's happening so far. Something it's forcing the views to be read from a different folder than the original one in Laravel. Maybe they are reading the views from this vendor folder that you suggested, hard to know. If you are using GIT, I recommend returning to a part of the code where this view files were working and debug from there to find out what caused them to stop working.

Comment: ok i will do so, thanks for your time

Comment: actually chatter is a package that is used to create forum discussions so I was adding comment functionality like this of stackoverflow and stuck in showing the comments.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $chatterreply =  new Chatterreply;
        $chatterreply->reply = $request->body;
        $chatterreply->chatter_post_id = $request->chatter_post_id;
        $chatterreply->chatter_discussion_id = $request->chatter_discussion_id;
        $chatterreply->save();
        return redirect('/discussion')->with('chatter_alert','Add Comment Successfully');
    }
```